# Create Custom grid css depending on Array Length

Tags: javascript, css, grid

I have array with data `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]` and I want to show 2 items on 1 line

```
<div class=row>
  <div>data1</div>
  <div>data2</div>
</div>
<div class=row>   
  <div>data3</div>
  ...
```

So I want do it with JS. As I understand I need smth like `[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7]]`, but cant understand how to make it. It'll be great if someone did it before and can help me.

Comment: do you need only the array rearranged or the part with the divs?

Comment: Can you please explain more? Do you want the js data to be formatted in html like you specified, or you have those divs and want them arranged 2 per line?

Comment: @NinaScholz great if both of it, but if you know only some part of it, please show it, thanks

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj I have array with data and need to create custom css/html grid based on (2 elements per line)

Answer (score 1):

Use JS and CSS Grid.

HTML:

```
    <div id=grid-wrapper">
      <div class="grid-item></div>
      <div class="grid-item></div>
      <div class="grid-item></div>
      <div class="grid-item></div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
    #grid-wrapper {
       display: grid;
    }
```

JavaScript:

```
    let dataArray = dataFromDB; // assuming data from API
    let numColumns = 4; // set number of columns    
    let grid = document.getElementById('grid-wrapper');
    // sets number of rows dynamically 
    grid.style.gridTemplateRows = `repeat(${Math.ciel(dataArray.length / numColumns)}, 1fr)`;
    grid.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${numColumns}, 1fr)`;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple `for` loop and increment by 2 and add to HTML

```js
var ar = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
for (var i = 0; i < ar.length; i += 2) {
  document.body.innerHTML += '<div class="row"><div>data' + ar[i] + '</div>' + ((ar[i + 1]) ? '<div>data' + (ar[i + 1]) + '</div>' : '') + '</div>';
}
```

```css
div div {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate and use the counter for grouping.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    div;

array.forEach(function (a, i) {
    var d = document.createElement('div');
    if (!(i & 1)) {
        div = document.createElement('div');
        document.body.appendChild(div);
    }
    d.innerText = a;
    div.appendChild(d);
});
```

```css
div div { float: left; width: 50%; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `mod` to see if it is even. This should get you started. You should also check for undefined in the index before outputting to screen - I did not implement that here.  If you are using bootstrap then this will work no prob. If not then you will need to have some css written.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var data = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7"];

    $.each(data, function (index, name) {
        // if divisible by 2
        if(index % 2 === 0  ) {
             // take index and add 1 to it
            var output = "<div class='row'> <div class='col-md-6'>" + data[index] + "</div> <div class='col-md-6'>" +data[index + 1] + "</div> </div>";
            console.log(output);
        }

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:  removed JQuery dependency

https://jsfiddle.net/r4kLddvh/

HTML:

```
<p id="parent"></p>
```

JS:

```
var data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];

function makeRow(a,b){
  a = !!a ? a : "";
  b = !!b ? b : "";
    return "<div class='row'><div class='cell'>"+a+"</div>" + "<div class='cell'>"+b+"</div></div>";
}

for(var i=0; i< data.length; i = i + 2){
    document.getElementById("parent").innerHTML += (makeRow(data[i], data[i+1]));
}
```

CSS:

```
.cell{
  display:table-cell;
  height:20px;
  width:20px;
  border:1px solid black;
}
.row{
  display:block;
}
```